# Lubuntu freezes

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, freeze

I'm trying to start using linux in my old computer (amd64 athlon x2 5200 / 2gb ram / 250gb hd) I downloaded lubuntu 16.04 Lts 32 bits. I created a bootable usb and started Lubuntu from usb to test.
I tried to use three times, and system froze (can't move cursor, and keyboard lights - numlock - capslock started to blink).
The first two tries I clicked in Firefox but it didn't start (freezing instantly), the third try I was verfying my computer settings in the control panel.

Could it be a problem because I'm running 32 bits on a amd64? 
Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got success to install Lubuntu:
I started the installation with the options: acpi = off / noapic / nomodeset.

Installed lubuntu normally, and the OS worked like a charm, subsequently I updated the video driver (NVIDIA).

I hope this serve someone who is having the same problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is probably not because you are loading a 32 bit OS on a 64 bit computer, but when I first installed Ubuntu It kept freezing because the graphics card couldn't support Unity. But lubuntu should run even on computer of those specs.

Try creating an install CD instead of a bootable USB, and check to see if the ISO is corrupted verifying its data integrity using the `md5sum` command:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: I made a new Lubuntu ISO download and burned on a DVD , I continue with the same problem , the system instantly freezes without any action , exactly the same thing happened with Xubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bits ) .